# How do I configure jboss log4j to avoid logging into server.log and instead write to a separate log file for a specifc java package?

Tags: java, logging, jboss

**Problem:-**

- Configure jboss log4j to log into a separate log file for the above referenced java package -- Resolved but needed your advise on the solution
- Configure jboss log4j to avoid logging to server.log for a specific java package

**Environment:-**

- App server (Jboss Eap 5.1) is configured and running on an Oracle Linux VM through Oracle Virtualbox Manager.

**My approach:-**

- I was able to successfully configure jboss to log to a separate file by modifying the jboss-log4j.xml to have a new appender (MYTESTLOGS) and a category for the package(com.mytestpackage) with reference to the new appender. But I cannot avoid jboss from logging to the server.log for that package.

**My jboss-log4j.xml:-**

```
   <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

   <!-- ================================= -->
   <!-- Preserve messages in a local file -->
   <!-- ================================= -->

   <!-- A time/date based rolling appender -->
   <appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log"/>
      <param name="Append" value="true"/>
      <!-- In AS 5.0.x the server log threshold was set by a system
           property. In 5.1 and later we are instead using the system
           property to set the priority on the root logger (see <root/> below)
      <param name="Threshold" value="${jboss.server.log.threshold}"/>
      -->

      <!-- Rollover at midnight each day -->
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>

      <!-- Rollover at the top of each hour
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH"/>
      -->

      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] (Thread) Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] [%X{sessionID}] (%t) %m%n"/>

         <!-- The full pattern: Date MS Priority [Category] (Thread:NDC) Message\n
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
          -->
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <!-- ============================== -->
   <!-- Append messages to the console -->
   <!-- ============================== -->

   <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>

      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

      <!-- Limit the jacorb category to WARN as its INFO is verbose -->
   <category name="jacorb">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Set the logging level of the JSF implementation that uses
      | java.util.logging. The jdk logging levels can be controlled
      | through the org.jboss.logging.log4j.JDKLevel class that
      | in addition to the standard log4j levels it adds support for
      | SEVERE, WARNING, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST
   -->
   <category name="javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf">
     <priority value="INFO" class="org.jboss.logging.log4j.JDKLevel"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the org.jgroups category to WARN as its INFO is verbose -->
   <category name="org.jgroups">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the org.quartz category to INFO as its DEBUG is verbose -->
   <category name="org.quartz">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the com.sun category to INFO as its FINE is verbose -->
   <category name="com.sun">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the sun category to INFO as its FINE is verbose -->
   <category name="sun">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the javax.xml.bind category to INFO as its FINE is verbose -->
   <category name="javax.xml.bind">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the springframework category to WARN-->
   <category name="org.springframework">
     <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category> 

   <!-- Limit the JSR77 categories -->
   <category name="org.jboss.management">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the verbose facelets compiler -->
   <category name="facelets.compiler">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the verbose ajax4jsf cache initialization -->
   <category name="org.ajax4jsf.cache">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the verbose embedded jopr categories -->
   <category name="org.rhq">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the verbose seam categories -->
   <category name="org.jboss.seam">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the verbose MC4J EMS (lib used by admin-console) categories -->
   <category name="org.mc4j.ems">
      <priority value="WARN"/>
   </category>

   <!-- Limit the org.jboss.serial (jboss-serialization) to INFO as its DEBUG is verbose -->
   <category name="org.jboss.serial">
      <priority value="INFO"/>
   </category>


   <!-- ============================================ -->
   <!-- Setup the appender and log file for Red logs -->
   <!-- ============================================ -->

    <appender name="MYTESTLOGS" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/mytestlogs.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <!-- The log message pattern -->
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n" />
        </layout>
   </appender>

   <category name="com.mytestpackage">
     <priority value="INFO" />
     <appender-ref ref="MYTESTLOGS"/>
   </category>


   <!-- ======================= -->
   <!-- Setup the Root category -->
   <!-- ======================= -->

   <root>
      <!-- 
         Set the root logger priority via a system property. Note this is parsed by log4j,
         so the full JBoss system property format is not supported; e.g.
         setting a default via ${jboss.server.log.threshold:WARN} will not work.         
       -->
      <priority value="${jboss.server.log.threshold}"/>
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FILE"/> 
   </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Make sure that your application has not included it's own copy of log4j.jar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Steve. I tried removing the "log4j" jar from the application but had no luck with avoiding the logs from getting on to server.log. I still see the logs getting printed on server.log and also in the mytestlogs.log

Comment: Try adding the attribute `additivity="false"` to your category